# c++ find similar string in map/vector

Tags: c++, string, find

Is there a c ++ function that finds all string occurrences above the map / vector that differ by max in 1 (generally n) character?

Possibly some procedure that would not be time consuming, ie not to do, for example, to program cycles and comparators.

Comment: Do the strings you intend to compare have the same length? I.e. `"hello"` vs `"hella"` or `"hello"` vs `"helloo"`?

Comment: yes same length

Comment: I don't think there's such a function in the standard but you can get away with a pretty simple `for` loop. Why isn't that feasible for you?

Answer (score 0):

No. It can't be common algorithm because people have varying ideas depending on concrete needs how to quantify "similarity" or "difference". It can not be made canonical.

So they specify it clearly for their use-case and then write their own `are_similar_enough(a, b)` filter predicate or `difference_of(a, b)` function.

Then they extract the similar elements from their container with `std::ranges::views::filter` or similar hand-made algorithm. I suggest you do same and if you have technical problems then ask.